# Angular 2: view does not update when array is updated

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a component with two array. `arrayA` and `arrayB`. `arrayB` contains filtered elements of `arrayA`. And in the template:

```
<div *ngFor="let elem of arrayB">{{elem.something}}</div>
```

I have a button too:

```
<button (click)="doSomething()">Do Something</button>
```

In the `doSomething` method I use the filter method on `arrayA` to update `arrayB`.

```
doSomething() {
    this.arrayB = this.arrayA.filter(elem => { return ***some code***; });
}
```

The problem is that the view doesn't refresh. I tried to use NgZone (ngZone.run(): I wrapped the code in the method.) and ChangeDetectorRef (detectChanges()/markForCheck(): I called this at the end of the method.) too.

What should be the solution for this?

Comment: pls `console.log(this.arrayB)` at last in `doSomething` func and see if there are actually any differences

Comment: You shouldn't have to mark anything as changed if the button click event happens inside the same template as the ngFor. You only have to tell Angular it's changed if it's outside the change tree or changed after it's been checked. Maybe the problem is that arrayB hasn't changed when you thought it should.

Comment: @Dhyey After I checked the array with `console.log(arrayB)`, I noticed a strange thing: the `doSomething()` fires twice. The first time, the `arrayB` is right (filtered), but the second time... it's the original. My `(click)` looks like this: `(click)="foo && !foo.bar && doSomething()"`. So I guess the problems are these 'conditions'.

Comment: @Dhyey I was wrong. Without the 'conditions', it still fires twice.

Comment: @RolandRácz can u pls reproduce it in a plnkr and post the link ?

Answer (score 1):

It should works ! make sure that your filter is working, please check this example:

```
<div *ngFor="let elemB of arrayB">{{elemB}}</div>
<strong>array A :</strong>
<div *ngFor="let elemA of arrayA">{{elemA}}</div>
<button (click)="doSomething()">Do Something</button>
```

TS :

```
 arrayA = [0,1,2,3,4];
 arrayB = [];

 doSomething(){ 
     this.arrayB = this.arrayA.filter(x => { return x > 2; });
 }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/VQYoVIGoioPwjW1ThcFQ?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It turns out that the filter is fine, but the `doSomething()` fires twice (even if I clicked only once). The first time, the `arrayB` is right, but the second time it's the original. The question is, why is this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the `doSomething()` method I returned with `true`. Because of this, the method fired twice.
So the solution is to always return with `false`.